# genymotion failed to write virtual device description file

Tags: virtual-machine, genymotion

If I launch Genymotion by the root user, it works well.But when I launch it by general user，I got this:[image]

Answer (score 0):

Devices created with Genymotion are linked to the user, so if you created a device as root, it won't show up when you start Genymotion as another user.

There are normally no reasons to run Genymotion as root, so I suggest you recreate the devices as your normal user.